# How to set open_files_limit on mariadb

Tags: mysql, mariadb, linux

I encountered a strange behavior and I would like to understand better what is happening.
I set in my.cnf the parameter open_files_limit = 32000 in the [mysql] section.
I restarted MariaDB. I have two processes mysqld_safe and mysql.

Result of ps:

```
root     10439     1  0 11:27 pts/1    00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe 
--datadir=/var/lib/mysql/data
--pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/data/rcentdb02.pid

mysql    10880 10439  0 11:27 pts/1    00:01:14 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr
--datadir=/var/lib/mysql/data --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --user=mysql
--log-error=/var/lib mysql/data/rcentdb02.err --open-files-limit=32000 
--pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/data/rcentdb02.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
--port=3306
```

Result of cat /proc/$(pgrep mysqld_safe$)/limits | grep "Max open":

```
Max open files            32000                32000                files
```

Result of cat /proc/$(pgrep mysqld$)/limits | grep "Max open":

```
Max open files            90162                90162                files
```

My question is: why mysql_safe have the good parameter for open_files_limit but not mysqld process?

Thanks.

---

The result of SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'open_files_limit' is 90162.
I tried to remove the open_files_limit from my.cnf but it does not work.

I have always this value 90162 which seem to be setup nowhere ...

Any idea?

---

I setup my.cnf to have:

```
[mysqld]
open_files_limit = 32000
[mysqld_safe]
open_files_limit = 32000
```

I stop mysql and start mysql.
Result of SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'open_files_limit'; => 90162

---

I changed the value of open_files_limit to 100000 and now the result of query SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'open_files_limit' is 100000. So now my question is : I understand that mysql may autoadjust this parameter but how he can choose a value (90162) higher than the system limit ... ?

With root account:

```
ulimit -Sn => 1024
ulimit -Hn => 4096
```

With mysql account (I changed nologin to bash for my test):

```
ulimit -Sn => 32000
ulimit -Hn => 64000
```

Comment: Does it matter?  `table_open_cache` is the real limit.  Plus a couple of `innodb_*` settings.  (No, I don't know where 90162 could be coming from.)

Answer (score 1):

You may have to login to MariaDB and run

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'open_files_limit';
```

and see if this is `32000` or `90162`. mysqld may be capping it.

It is entirely possible that [open_files_limit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_open-files-limit) is getting autoadjusted. The Documentation says `Default:5000, with possible adjustment` and `Maximum:platform dependent`.

Here is how [`mysqld_safe`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqld-safe.html) and [`mysqld`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqld.html) interact:

- [`mysqld_safe`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqld-safe.html) will pass values to [`mysqld`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqld.html)
- [`mysqld`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqld.html) may override values passed from [`mysqld_safe`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqld-safe.html)

According to MySQL Documentation on [`mysqld_safe`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqld-safe.html):

> Many of the options to mysqld_safe are the same as the options to mysqld. See Section 5.1.4, “Server Command Options”.
>
> Options unknown to mysqld_safe are passed to mysqld if they are specified on the command line, but ignored if they are specified in the [mysqld_safe] group of an option file. See Section 4.2.6, “Using Option Files”.

What you may need to do is remove `open_files_limit` from my.cnf and let [`mysqld_safe`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqld-safe.html) assign the value it knows to [`mysqld`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqld.html).

Then, restart [`mysqld`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqld.html).

## UPDATE 2018-02-28 08:24 EST

You may need to add `[mysqld_safe]` header in `my.cnf` and put `open_files_limit=32000`, like this:

```
[mysqld_safe]
open_files_limit=32000
```

However, don't restart mysqld. This may not properly terminate [`mysqld_safe`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqld-safe.html) because it contains an indefinite loop to check the return code of [`mysqld`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqld.html) when it terminates. There is a certain return value that lets `mysqld_safe` know to relaunch `mysqld`. This means that mysqld_safe does not terminate when it handle a `mysqld` restart.

It is better to do the restart in two steps

```
service mysql stop && service mysql start
```

Doing `service mysql stop` will terminate `mysqld` and then exit the indefinite loop in `mysqld_safe`, terminating `mysqld_safe`. Then, launching `service mysql start` will launch a fresh `mysqld_safe` process. Give it a try and let us know.

If you cannot edit `my.cnf`, then specify the option on the command-line:

```
service mysql stop && service mysql start --open-files-limit=32000
```

Comment: The result of SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'open_files_limit' is 90162. I tried to remove the open_files_limit from my.cnf but it does not work.

I have always this value 90162 which seem to be setup nowhere ...

Any other idea?

Comment: I had mentioned that mysqld may autoadjust. Try setting `open_files_limit=100000`(which is larger that 90162), stop mysql, and start mysql and see.